# Search function not displaying correct records PHP

Tags: html

```
<form id = "gameYear" method="get" action="result.php">
<label> 
    Game Year
    <select name="gameYear">
       <option value="2001">2001</option>
       <option value="2002">2002</option>
    </select>
</label>
   <input type = "submit" name="search" value = "Search">
</form>


<?php
include 'dbConnection.php'; 

$gameYear = $_GET['gameYear'];
$query = "SELECT gameSerial, gameTitle, gameYear, gameCost FROM games WHERE 1 AND gamesYear <='$gamesYear'";


mysqli_free_result($Games); 
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Now the HTML Form submits and links to the database ok, however, the records do not match. For example if I select "2001" it will pull back other records, not just from 2001. I'm new to PHP and I don't know if I'm missing something obvious. I've done a little searching but to be honest I'm not entirely sure what to search so thought I'd ask. Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right tracks but the operator you are using is not the correct one.
`1 AND gamesYear <='$gamesYear'` will find all games published before or on the supplied year.
The equality operator is the one you need:
`1 AND gamesYear ='$gamesYear'`

Also, you can do away with the 1 AND entirely as it does not add to your query.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was trying different years in the search and it was pulling back random results and I couldn't work it out. Knew it would be something simple. 

Say I wanted to now add more search options in my form, what do I change in my SQL/PHP? Do I not need WHERE 1 at all? Do I just use AND? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.
The AND operator tells the query to only return results where both operands evaluate to true.
1 will always evaluate to true and gameYear="2001" will only evaluate to true for records from that year.
The 1 bit is a constant and hence won't have an impact on what you return.
If you want to add another search criterion. For example, only return games that are cheaper than £10, you could use this as your WHERE:
`WHERE gameYear = 2001 AND gameCost < "10"`

Comment: Thanks, understand it much better now. I do have one final question though. If I was to add an "All Years" option to my HTML Form how would I get this to work with PHP? As I add more fields to my form it would be beneficial if the user could just see all the games without having to select a year unless they want to, to narrow down the search. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: No worries at all. Concatenation is your friend, here:

`
// Create an initial query which returns everything
$query = "SELECT gameSerial, gameTitle, gameYear, gameCost FROM games";
if ($_GET['gameYear']) {
    // Note the .= operator which will concatenate the right side operand with the currect query
    $gameYear = intval($_GET['gameYear']);
    $query .= " WHERE gameYear = '$gameYear'";
}
`

Comment: Thanks again, been a big help!

Comment: Hi, I'm still having a little trouble. I have concatenated the various fields which means the user can fill any combination of fields and doesn't need to complete them all. However, for the 'any' option, I'm not sure how to do it. It's my understanding the option value in the form links to the database? EG, if I used concatenation for the following query `WHERE gameCost < "10"` how would I add this option to the HTML Form? I feel like I am missing something out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but try changing your query to this

```
 $sql = "SELECT gameSerial, gameTitle, gameYear, gameCost FROM games WHERE gamesYear ='$gameYear'";
```

I'm not sure what the 'WHERE 1' and... thing was

Also, you added an extra s to your PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

Note the last of your SQL:

```
AND gamesYear <='$gamesYear'";
```

The variable you GET is gameYear - without the s.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT gameSerial, gameTitle, gameYear, gameCost FROM games WHERE 1 AND gamesYear ='$gameYear'";
```

What happens if you skip the < as shown above? Also I think you made a typo in the variable name.

Comment: Good spot!
Although I imagine this is a typo from typing the question, otherwise Ronaldo would be getting Unknown column errors.

Comment: Yes, was a typo. Thanks for the reply though. The place I was using as reference didn't really explain and I thought the '<' was required but seeing it now it's quite evident it isn't. Cheers for the reply, much appreciated.